# Who is driving Thomas Jane's hair and wardrobe on the Expanse?

Tags: character, costume, make-up, the-expanse

Who is driving Thomas Jane's hair and wardrobe on the Expanse? I ask because his hair and wardrobe, particularly in Season 2, seem to be a nod to [Mœbius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Giraud), [Tamburini & Liberatore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RanXerox) and the art of [Heavy Metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_(magazine)) in general, in contrast to the more conventional look of the overall show.

My guess is that Jane himself is driving his character's look, possibly as a fan of the artists I mentioned, facilitated by wardrobe and makeup people with an appreciation of that aesthetic.

I'd be interested in any info on the look of Josephus Miller, Jane's character on the show.

Comment: "My guess is that Jane himself is driving his character's look" Based on what?

Comment: Ju@BCdotWEB just that Jane is the name star on the show, and likely has some clout.  He's just the right age to have been a fan of heavy metal magazine, and as an actor, in terms of the craft, he's one of those who always delivers an interesting performance. I say guess because it is pure speculation, but his look is quite distinct, so someone is making that decision.  Most likely it is the hair and wardrobe people, or a producer, but again, Jane is an interesting actor...

Answer (score 4):

> My guess is that Jane himself is driving his character's look, possibly as a fan of the artists I mentioned, facilitated by wardrobe and makeup people with an appreciation of that aesthetic.

As far as I'm aware, there is no proof of that.

However, there is a tiny bit of supporting evidence that Joe Miller (the character played by Jane) drives his own personal style.

> **Miller's partner** What's the deal with the hat?
>     **Miller** Keeps the rain off my head.

(I can't recall Miller's partner's name at the moment)

Miller's response is bullshit, since there is no weather inside a space station. He chooses to wear the hat for personal style reasons, and only forgoes it when necessary (e.g. wearing a space suit).

If Miller wears the hat out of a personal sense of style, it stands to reason that he does the same for his hair and wardrobe, since they all seem to fit the same general aesthetic.
It also fits with Miller's personality. He doesn't care what people think of him, he simply does what he feels is the right thing to do. Miller's sense of style is questionable both in-universe and out-of-universe, but Miller does not feel any shyness about who he chooses to be.

**Edit**
As to Miller's style clashing with the general attire of the Belters; that can be done to justify how Miller doesn't belong. He is from somewhere else, and a contrarian at heart; so the show's creators (and the author of the book) can use this as a way of visualizing Miller not fitting in with the crowd.